# program that asks 5 numbers and in the end return two biggest numbers

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I came up with the solution to this problem to find the two biggest numbers. but it doesn't valid if I input values in increasing orders ex 2, 3 ,4 ,5, 6! what will be the solution for that problem?

```
let first_biggest_number = 0;
let second_biggest_number = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  let number = Number.parseInt(window.prompt("Enter your number oi"));

  if (number > first_biggest_number) {
    first_biggest_number = number;
  } else {
    second_biggest_number = number;
  }
}
console.log(first_biggest_number);
console.log(second_biggest_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the biggest number, the old biggest should now be the second biggest.

Then you're not checking whether the number is bigger than the second biggest number before replacing it. So the second number will be the last number that's not biggest.

```js
let first_biggest_number = 0;
let second_biggest_number = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  let number = Number.parseInt(window.prompt("Enter your number oi"));

  if (number > first_biggest_number) {
    second_biggest_number = first_biggest_number;
    first_biggest_number = number;
  } else if (number > second_biggest_number) {
    second_biggest_number = number;
  }
}
console.log(first_biggest_number);
console.log(second_biggest_number);
```